# toString() method for a linked list sequence

Tags: java

I'm having trouble writing a toString() method for a linked sequence class.
I can't seem to figure out what I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The one implemented now doesn't display the list when I call the addAfter() method.

Here's the code"

```
public class DoubleLinkSeq implements Cloneable { 

     private int manyNodes;  // keeps track of the number of nodes in the list
        private IntNode head;   // reference to the first node
        private IntNode tail;   // reference to the last node
        private IntNode cursor; // refers to the node with the current element (or null)
        private IntNode precursor;  // refers to the node before the current element (or null)

        /**
         * Constructor for the IntLinkedSeq class
         * Initialize an empty sequence
         */
        public DoubleLinkSeq() {
            head = null;
            tail = null;
            cursor = null;
            precursor = head;
            manyNodes = 0;
        }

        /**
         * Adds a new element to this sequence before the current element
         *
         * @param element - the new element that is being added
         */
        public void addBefore(int element) {
            if (isCurrent()) {  // if there is a current element
                if (cursor == head) {  // where cursor is the head
                    precursor = new IntNode(element, cursor);  // add new node
                    head = precursor;  // move head;
                } else {  // if cursor is not the head
                    precursor.addNodeAfter(element);  // add new node
                    cursor = precursor.getLink();  // move cursor
                }
            }
            else{  // if no current element
                if(head == null){
                    head = new IntNode(element, null);
                    cursor = head;  // move cursor
                    precursor = head;  // move precursor
                    tail = head;  // move tail
                }
                else{  // otherwise, add the node after the precursor, before cursor
                    precursor.addNodeAfter(element);  // add after precursor
                }
            }

            manyNodes++;  // update the invariant

        }

        /**
         * Adds a new element to this sequence after the current element
         *
         * @param element - the new element that is being added
         * @exception OutOfMemoryError
         *   Indicates insufficient memory for a new node
         */
        public void addAfter(int element) {
            if (isCurrent()) {  
                cursor.addNodeAfter(element);  
                precursor = cursor;        
                cursor = cursor.getLink(); 
            }
            else{  
                if(tail == null){  
                    tail = new IntNode(element, null); 
                    cursor = tail;      
                    precursor = tail;   
                    head = tail;        
                }
                else{  
                    tail.addNodeAfter(element);  
                    precursor = tail;       
                    tail = tail.getLink();  
                    cursor = tail;          
                }
                manyNodes++;  
            }
        }

        /**
         * Place the contents of another sequence at the end of this sequence
         * @param addend - A sequence that will be placed at the end of this sequence
         */
        public void addAll(DoubleLinkSeq addend){
            IntNode[] copy;

            if(addend == null){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("addend is null");
            }

            if(addend.size() > 0){
                copy = IntNode.listCopyWithTail(addend.head);
                tail.getLink().setLink(copy[0]);  // set what used to be the last node to the start of the new list
                copy[1].setLink(null);  // set link of last item to null
                tail.setLink(copy[0]);  // set tail link to the first element of the copy
                manyNodes += addend.size();  // update the invariant
            }
        }

        /**
         * Determine the number of elements in this sequence
         * @return 
         */
        public int size() {
            return manyNodes;
        }

        /**
         * Accessor method to determine whether this sequence has a specified
         * current element that can be retrieved with the getCurrent method
         *
         * @return True if there is a current element, otherwise false
         */
        public boolean isCurrent() {
            if (cursor == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Accessor method to determine the current element of the sequence Note:
         * isCurrent must return true
         *
         * @return The current element of the sequence
         */
        public int getCurrent() {
            if(!isCurrent()){
                throw new IllegalStateException("isCurrent() is null: there is no current element");
            }

            // return the integer value of data at cursor
            return cursor.getData();
        }

        /**
         * Move forward, so that the current element is now the next element in this sequence
         * Note: isCurrent() must return true
         */
        public void advance() {
            if (isCurrent()) {
                precursor = cursor;         // move the precursor to where the cursor is
                cursor = cursor.getLink();  // advance the current element forward to the next link
            } else {
                // at end of sequence, do nothing
            }
        }

        /**
         * Generate a copy of this sequence
         * @return A copy of this sequence. Subsequent changes to the copy will not affect the original and vice versa.
         * @throws CloneNotSupportedException 
         */
        @Override
        public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
            DoubleLinkSeq answer;

            try{
                answer = (DoubleLinkSeq) super.clone();
            }
            catch(CloneNotSupportedException e){
                throw new RuntimeException("This class does not implement Cloneable.");
            }

            answer.head = IntNode.listCopy(head);

            return answer;
        }

        public static DoubleLinkSeq concatenation(DoubleLinkSeq s1, DoubleLinkSeq s2){
            if( (s1 == null) || (s2 == null) ){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("s1 or s2 is null");
            }

            DoubleLinkSeq answer = new DoubleLinkSeq();

            answer.addAll(s1);  // add all from the first sequence
            answer.addAll(s2);  // add all from the second sequence

            // Return the union IntLinkedSeq object
            return answer;
        }

        /**
         * Remove the current element from this sequence
         * Note: if there is no current element, removeCurrent must not be called
         */
        public void removeCurrent(){
            if(!isCurrent()){
                throw new IllegalStateException("isCurrent() is null");
            }

            if(tail == head){  // only one node case
                head = null;
                tail = null;
                precursor = head;
                manyNodes--;  // update invariant
                return;
            }

            if(cursor == tail){  // if cursor is at the last node
                tail = precursor;   // remove the last node
                tail.setLink(null);
                cursor = tail;      // move cursor
                precursor = head;   // move precursor to beginning
                while(precursor.getLink() != cursor){
                    // search for a link for precursor
                    if(precursor.getLink() == null){
                        break;
                    }
                    precursor = precursor.getLink();
                }

                manyNodes--;  // update invariant
                return;
            }

            if(cursor == head){  // if cursor is at the first node
                head = head.getLink();
                cursor = head;
                precursor = head;
                manyNodes--;  // update invariant
                return;
            }

            // regular case
            cursor = cursor.getLink();
            precursor.setLink(cursor);
            manyNodes--;  // update invariant
        }

        /**
         * Set the current element at the front of this sequence
         */
        public void start(){
            if(head == null){  // if there are no elements in the sequence
                cursor = null; // no cursor
            }

            cursor = head;  // move cursor to the first node
            precursor = head;
        }

        public String toString() {
            String result = "";
            if (head == null)
                return manyNodes + "";
            else

             cursor = head;
            while(cursor.getLink() != null){
                cursor = cursor.getLink();
                result += cursor.getLink() + ", ";
            }
            return "List: " + result;
        }
}
```

Comment: what do you get after calling the `toString()` ?

Comment: @RajithPemabandu I get its memory address

Comment: You do know that "update the invariant" is an oxymoron, right? "update" (change) + "invariant" (unchanged) = "oxymoron" (contradictory terms)

Comment: @Andreas True. Sorry, English is not my first language.

Comment: You form the string output by calling cursor.getLink(). The variable cursor is an IntNode object. I'm not sure which IntNode it is, as IntNode of Java 8 doesn't have a getLink() method. But that's where your problem lies. I am guessing getLink() returns a certain object class, which does not override toString(), so the default implementation which returns the instance's hash code is used.

Comment: how is IntNode implemented ? Please provide details on IntNode. Need to see what getLink() function does ?

Answer (score 0):

try adding curly braces around your else statement so it'll look something like this:

```
    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        if (head == null)
            return manyNodes + "";
        else{//add here
            cursor = head;
            while(cursor.getLink() != null){
                cursor = cursor.getLink();
                result += cursor.getLink() + ", ";
            }
            return "List: " + result;
       }//and here
    }
```

Comment: Still the same problem. When I call it I only get a memory location

Comment: how is IntNode implemented ? Please provide details on IntNode. Need to see what getLink() function does ?